# How do I access the request params in order to authenticate an user

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I would like to write a simple login form for my App. It is just a simple form, which sends data via post request to the django server. 
For authentification, I have to access the post request data, as mentioned in the django documentation but this doesn't work properly.

This is my html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login/">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ID">User</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ID" aria-describedby="User" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Passwort</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" laceholder="Passwort">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Einloggen</button>
</form>
```

This is my django code:

```
def get_access(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['ID']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
```

I get this Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'App',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  77.             list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('ID'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\Animoo\App\views.py" in get_access
  163.         username = request.POST['ID']

File "C:\Users\felix\DEV\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  79.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /login/
Exception Value: 'ID'
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTML form uses the [**`name=...`** [html.com]](https://html.com/attributes/input-name/) attribute to create key-value pairs, *not* the <s>`id=...`</s>. So you should specify the name, as is specified in the documentation:

> Specifies the name of an input element. The name and value of each input element are **included in the HTTP request** when the form is submitted.

thus you should add `name` attributes, like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login/">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ID">User</label>
<input name="ID" type="text" class="form-control" id="ID" aria-describedby="User" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Passwort</label>
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" laceholder="Passwort">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Einloggen</button>
</form>
```

The `id=...` is used to identify objects in the DOM, and for example use JavaScript, etc. to dynamically change the HTML content. You thus can still keep the `id="..."` attribute, but it is not functional when you submit the form.